# Expanding lists during a 'while' loop

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I have this dataset

```
  Name1 Name2   Score
    John    Chris   15.4
    John    Luke    11.0
    John    Martin  10.1
    John    Paul    8.7
    John    Patty   8.0
    Patty   Stephanie   21.6
    Patty   Mila    21.6
    Patty   Martin  19.7
    Patty   Chris   17.2
    Patty   Luke    15.9
    Meghan  Kate    5.0
    Meghan  Chris   4.2
    Meghan  William 4.1
    Meghan  John    3.2
    Meghan  Stephen 3.0
```

I determined the distinct values and the differences:

```
next_name2 = df['Name2']                
name1 = df['Name1']  
distinct_name1 = set(name1)
diff = set(next_name2) - distinct_name1
```

getting

```
   diff = {'Stephen', 'Martin', 'Chris', 'Stephanie', 'Paul', 'Luke', 'Mila', 'Kate', 'William'}
```

Since the length of diff is greater than 0, I am running the following:

```
while len(diff) > 0:
    new_run= [fun(x) for x in diff] 
    next_name2.append(new_run)    
    name1.append(diff)        
    unique_source.update(diff)
```

But I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The function `fun` has the following structure:

```
name2_list, score_list = [],[]

def fun(df):
    
    for x in df['Name1']: 
        
        url = "https://www.website.com/siteinfo/"+ x
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

       name_i = soup.select("#card_mini_audience .site>a")   
       score_i = soup.select("#card_mini_audience .overlap>.truncation") 

       name_i = [name_x.text.strip() for name_x in name_i]
       score_i = [float(score_x.text.strip()) for score_x in score_i]  
        for pair in zip(name_i, score_i):
            print(pair)
        name2_list.append(name_i)
        score_list.append(score_i)
        
    
    return name2_list, score_list.append
```

Every time I run the function, I get a list like this:

for `x = Stephen`

```
('Julie', 31.9)
('Mike', 30.9)
('Catherine', 30.7)
('Molly', 29.0)
```

for `x = Martin`:

```
('John', 34)
```

for `x = Chris`:

```
('Luke', 12)
('Jane', 32)
```

and so on, `for x in diff`.
The while loop should end when all the `name2` are in the list, i.e., when `len(diff)` is 0.

The error seems to be caused by `for x in df['Name1']:`, and I think the problem is that, every time I run the function within the while loop, I have values expressed as lists.
So, for example,

```
  Name1 Name2   Score
    John    Chris   15.4
    John    Luke    11.0
    John    Martin  10.1
    John    Paul    8.7
    John    Patty   8.0
    Patty   Stephanie   21.6
    Patty   Mila    21.6
    Patty   Martin  19.7
    Patty   Chris   17.2
    Patty   Luke    15.9
    Meghan  Kate    5.0
    Meghan  Chris   4.2
    Meghan  William 4.1
    Meghan  John    3.2
    Meghan  Stephen 3.0
    Stephen ['Julie','Mike','Catherine','Molly'] [31.9,30.9,30.7,29.0]
    Martin  ['John'] [34]
    Chris   ['Luke','Jane'] [12, 32]
```

so it needs to be expanded (every time, until I have all the name2 in `Name1` column).

Do you have any idea on how I can fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line you are calling the function with an item from `diff`, which is apparently a set of strings:

```
new_run = [fun(x) for x in diff]
```

However, it looks like `fun()` expects its argument to be a Pandas `DataFrame` object.

In order to fix this issue, you need to call the function with the correct argument or arguments.

Without more information it's not possible to tell you how to do that. Did you mean to define `fun()` like this?

```
def fun(df, x):
    ...
```

In this case, you should call it like this (assuming `df` is defined elsewhere in the scope):

```
new_run = [fun(df, x) for x in diff]
```

As general programming advice, I recommend you add comments and [docstrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring#Python) to your code to help you keep track of what the different variables mean and what their types are. If you want, you can even add [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) to your code and use a tool like [MyPy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to check them.

Comment: thanks for your answer, @augurar, and for your advice. I updated the questions with all the steps in the function. You can think of `df` as the first table in my question. I applied the changes that you suggested and I do not get that error anymore. However, it seems that it is not considering the differences and what is included in `Name`1 as it is checking the same `Name1`, getting always the same `Name2` observations. So something is still going wrong. It seems that it is not checking at all within the two lists of distinct and differences

Comment: In the function you are iterating `for x in df['Name1']`.  This will loop over every value in the `Name1` column of the data frame.  I think you should post your question on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) which is more geared toward helping new programmers learn to program and write better code.

Comment: I did not know about code review stack exchange. Thanks for letting me know. Unfortunately, I am still not understanding how to consider the difference. Should I replace `df['Name1']` with `diff`?

Comment: @Val Sorry, but Stack Overflow is for solving a specific question or problem (e.g. "Why is this code throwing a `TypeError`?", which I believe I have already answered.)  I can't tell you how to write your code line by line.